# how to solve react native execute code previously

Tags: javascript, react-native

Previously, my code was wrong to make an error, then I made changes and reloaded my emulator, and the metro bundler still issued the same error as the program code I made

when I run react-native run-android, the program runs perfectly

```
import React from 'react'
import {Image,View,Text,StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator,ToastAndroid,PermissionsAndroid,BackAndroid} from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

error returned in metro bundler:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: 

D:\Projects\beechatt\src\Screens\Pages\Splashcreen.js: Identifier 'ToastAndroid' has already been declared (2:66)

  1 | import React from 'react'
  2 | import {Image,View,Text,StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator,ToastAndroid,ToastAndroid,PermissionsAndroid,BackAndroid} from 'react-native'
    |                                                                   ^
  3 | import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
  4 | export default class Profile extends React.Component{
  5 |
```

thats is difrent, what I write and what is output is very different

Comment: Close metro bundler terminal and save you file and try to again run your project

Comment: Yes, but isn't effective, can I run without re-run metro bundler ???